# Flask-Dance uses localhost instead of domain when redirecting

Tags: flask, google-oauth, flask-dance

I have an app which is using Flask-Dance for Google Login authentication. When I try to login, it says that I am redirecting from 127.0.0.1:9852 which is where my app is running in the server, but I have an apache configuration which is assigning a server name to that address (xxx.xxx.com)

I registered in my Google Console the domain in the authorized URIs. Still, when I try to access the login part, it says that 'The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:9852/google/authorized, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.'

So I did register that address, and it does let me login, but when it tries to redirect it says that it can't find the server '127.0.0.1'. Is there anyway I can use my domain as the actual authorized URI?

This is my blueprint:

```
blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id="id",
    client_secret="secret",
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
           'openid'],
    storage=SQLAlchemyStorage(OAuth, db.session, user=current_user),
    redirect_url='questions.view_all')
```

**EDIT**: Here is the Apache2 conf file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName xxx.xxx.com
            ServerAlias xxx.xxx.com
            ServerAdmin em@il.com
            # Redirect http to https
            RedirectMatch 301 (.*) https://xxx.xxx.com$1
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerName xxx.xxx.com
            ServerAlias xxx.xxx.com
            ServerAdmin em@il.com

            #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
            SSLEngine On
            SSLProxyEngine On

            # Web root
            ProxyPass /  http://127.0.0.1:9852/
            ProxyPassReverse /  http://127.0.0.1:9852/

            # Log configuration
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            # Self signed SSL Certificate file
            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/cert.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/cert.key
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I registered in my Google Console the domain in the authorized URIs

The [full redirect URL should be registered](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance-google#step-2-get-oauth-credentials-from-google) for the OAUTH client application in Google Console.

> When I try to login, it says that I am redirecting from 127.0.0.1:9852

Your given server configuration has your application served with gunicorn and Apache configured as a proxy server.

In some way the request isn't passed onto gunicorn server with enough information for [werkzeug to determine the right hostname](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/0.16.0/src/werkzeug/wsgi.py#L145).

I suggest employing [`ProxyPreserveHost` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) in your `VirtualHost` to enable the incoming host to be passed on to gunicorn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The application exists in a Docker container, being served using gunicorn. I have edited the apache conf file for reference. Also, I am registering the full URL, including https.

Comment: Thanks again for answering! The directive definitely worked and now my requests are being received through my domain. The only problem I'm having now is that it is redirecting as http and not as https. I could turn on insecure transport, but I definitely do not want to do that.

Comment: You probably need Apache to set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to make Flask generate HTTPS URLs. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#deploying-proxy-setups